# Error Python Webserver 3.11.2 by testing Solidity contract

Tags: python-3.x, solidity, contract

I tried to test some Solidity contracs with Pyton Webserver 3 to interact by web-UI with Metamask. Pyton is working fine, but I only get the project directory not the desired webUI with a button and Pyton sends

```
::ffff:127.0.0.1 - - [14/Feb/2023 16:18:25] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
::ffff:127.0.0.1 - - [15/Feb/2023 10:13:58] "GET /src/ HTTP/1.1" 200 -
::ffff:127.0.0.1 - - [15/Feb/2023 10:14:04] code 404, message File not found
::ffff:127.0.0.1 - - [15/Feb/2023 10:14:04] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 -
----------------------------------------
Exception occurred during processing of request from ('::ffff:127.0.0.1', 62286, 0, 0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\GCC-V\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\http\server.py", line 726, in send_head
    f = open(path, 'rb')
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\_jpegdegens\\favicon.ico'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\GCC-V\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\socketserver.py", line 691, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "C:\Users\GCC-V\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\http\server.py", line 1306, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self,
  File "C:\Users\GCC-V\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\http\server.py", line 667, in __init__
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\GCC-V\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\socketserver.py", line 755, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "C:\Users\GCC-V\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\http\server.py", line 432, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()
  File "C:\Users\GCC-V\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\http\server.py", line 420, in handle_one_request
    method()
  File "C:\Users\GCC-V\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\http\server.py", line 671, in do_GET
    f = self.send_head()
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\GCC-V\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\http\server.py", line 728, in send_head
    self.send_error(HTTPStatus.NOT_FOUND, "File not found")
  File "C:\Users\GCC-V\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\http\server.py", line 487, in send_error
    self.wfile.write(body)
  File "C:\Users\GCC-V\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\socketserver.py", line 834, in write
    self._sock.sendall(b)
ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
----------------------------------------
```

I'm not sure, if that's a problem with Pyton itself or if something's missing in index.ts

```
import { ethers } from "ethers";

function getEth() 
{
    // @ts-ignore
    const eth = window.etherium;
    if (!eth) 
    {
        throw new Error("please get Metamask");
    }
    return eth;
}

async function hasAccounts() 
{
    const eth = getEth();
    const accounts = await eth.request({method: "eth_accounts"}) as string[];
    return accounts && accounts.length;
}

async function requestAccounts() 
{
    const eth = getEth();
    const accounts = await eth.request({method: "eth_requestAccounts"}) as string[];
    return accounts && accounts.length;
}

async function run() 
{
    if (!await hasAccounts() && !await requestAccounts())
    {
    throw new Error("Please let me take your money");  
    }
    const counter = new ethers.Contract
    (
        process.env.CONTRACT_ADDRESS,
        [
            "function count() public",
            "function function getCounter() public view returns(uint)",
        ],
        new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(getEth()).getSigner()

    )
    const el = document.createElement("div");
    async function setCounter() 
    {
        el.innerHTML = await counter.getCounter();
    }
    setCounter();
    const button = document.createElement("button");
    button.innerText = "increment";
    button.onclick = async function() 
    {
        await counter.count();
        

        //setCounter();
    }
    document.body.appendChild(el);
    document.body.appendChild(button);
}

run();
```

index.html and index.ts are in the same directory named /src and if I go into that directory in the localhost-Window it only shows an empty screen, Source code

```
<html>
    <head>
        <body></body>
    </head>
</html>
```

Is there a better webserver than Pyton to test contracts on localshost?

starting Python and calling/ refresing localhost:8000

Comment: It is trying to open a file. Because your traceback is incomplete, it is not possible to tell why it is opening file, which file and why it is failing. Please edit the question and include relevant details.

Comment: traceback edited..

Answer (score 0):

Your web server expects a favicon

```
Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\_jpegdegens\\favicon.ico
```

I would assume adding this file will make your web server to function properly.

Wikipedia has more information what is a favicon and how to create one.

Comment: the great Error is gone now, but there's stiil a 304 - Not Modified error when i call the http-file

Serving HTTP on :: port 8000 (http://[::]:8000/) ...
::ffff:127.0.0.1 - - [17/Feb/2023 15:13:37] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
::ffff:127.0.0.1 - - [17/Feb/2023 15:13:50] "GET /src/ HTTP/1.1" 304